# React native photo editor stop issue

Tags: react-native

[image]

I have use react-native-photo-editor library to design the image, When I open the app I'm getting this alert automatically.

here is my code and screenshot.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { RNPhotoEditor } from 'react-native-photo-editor';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {}
  render() {
    return RNPhotoEditor.Edit({
      path: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/image.jpg'
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just I have rendered the element with View tag the alert gone and app working